# Infinite WHILE loop, results would be listed more then one time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am validating the source vs. target count; if there are more counts in the target than in the source table, the number would be negative, so I am trying to list all records that are missing in the source or target. If the number is negative, I get a list of records that repeats itself; 'while loop' is infinite.

In the temp table #results are next:

| src_object | src_total_cnt | trgt_object | trgt_total_cnt | Object | Differance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| source | 1 | Target | 150823 | Diff | -150822 |

Expected results: If there is a difference between the source and target list all records that are missing.
My part of the code is next:

```
select * from #results

DECLARE @R INT;
SET @R  = 0;

WHILE (select differance from #results) > @R
BEGIN 
select                                                                             
          s.SubscriptionUUID as src_subscription_id
         ,s.ContractUUID as src_contract_id
         ,ds.SubscriptionUUID as trgt_SubscriptionUUID
         ,ds.ContractUUID as trgt_ContractUUID
    FROM #subscription as s
        FULL JOIN [IPaaSDM].[dbo].[DimSubscription]     AS ds
            ON s.SubscriptionUUID = ds.SubscriptionUUID
        where s.SubscriptionUUID is null or ds.SubscriptionUUID is null
set @R = @R +1 
end;

--select * from #results

DECLARE @R1 INT;
SET @R1  = 0;

WHILE (select differance from #results) < @R1
BEGIN 

select                                                                             
          s.SubscriptionUUID as src_subscription_id
         ,s.ContractUUID as src_contract_id
         ,ds.SubscriptionUUID as trgt_SubscriptionUUID
         ,ds.ContractUUID as trgt_ContractUUID
    FROM #subscription as s
        FULL JOIN [IPaaSDM].[dbo].[DimSubscription]     AS ds
            ON s.SubscriptionUUID = ds.SubscriptionUUID
        where 1 = 1
        and s.SubscriptionUUID is null or ds.SubscriptionUUID is null

set @R1 = @R1 + 1 
end
```

Some simple few records that I am expecting to get on the end:

| src_subscription_id | src_contract_id | trgt_SubscriptionUUID | trgt_ContractUUID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | 1FE234FB-7A23-56DD | 95731B02-1010 |
| NULL | NULL | ADA88A23-40A6-4E0B | 560010B8-2312 |

Comment: your sql doesn't make much sense without some testdata, but shouldn't it be: `set @R1 = @R1 - 1`

Comment: I tried that as well with Set @R1 - 1 it's still infinite.

Comment: If you continuously increment `@R1` inside a `WHILE (SomeInvariant) < @R1` loop, then the loop runs either zero times, or infinite times. It's like that in every programming language.

Comment: well, what's the value of differance in your table. Also, why do you want to loop? you don't change the inner result in any form

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help, you almost certainly don't need a loop.

Comment: looping 150000 times will take a while...

Comment: It won't be that much, never I was just testing my code.

Comment: It will be that much in the second loop if `#results.difference` starts with a value of -150822, `@R1` starts with a value of 0, and you subtracting 1 from `@R1` on each iteration. The second query will have to run 150823 times for `@R1` to reach the value -150823, terminating the loop.

Comment: I need just one list of records that is missing, what should I use instead of WHILE loop?

Comment: Have you tried a left join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things, trying to use a loop when a single select may serve your needs. Also, an issue with using `difference` to check for changes is that if both source and target have records not in the other, you may still have difference = 0, or difference may understate the overall changes.

The loops in your code are repeatedly selecting what appear to be the same result set. I don't understand the intent if this logic. If you really only need a single result set, as shown in your expected results, a single query may do.

```
SELECT
    s.SubscriptionUUID as src_subscription_id
    ,s.ContractUUID as src_contract_id
    ,ds.SubscriptionUUID as trgt_SubscriptionUUID
    ,ds.ContractUUID as trgt_ContractUUID
FROM #subscription as s
FULL OUTER JOIN IPaaSDM.dbo.DimSubscription AS ds
    ON s.SubscriptionUUID = ds.SubscriptionUUID
WHERE s.SubscriptionUUID is null OR ds.SubscriptionUUID is null
```

Note that this will list missing or extra rows, but will not include rows where any other data differs.

If you need to separately list missing vs extra rows, run the query twice as `LEFT` or `RIGHT` joins different `WHERE` conditions.

```
SELECT ...
FROM #subscription as s
LEFT JOIN IPaaSDM.dbo.DimSubscription AS ds
    ON s.SubscriptionUUID = ds.SubscriptionUUID
WHERE ds.SubscriptionUUID is null

SELECT ...
FROM #subscription as s
RIGHT JOIN IPaaSDM.dbo.DimSubscription AS ds
    ON s.SubscriptionUUID = ds.SubscriptionUUID
WHERE s.SubscriptionUUID is null
```

(If you have an aversion to `RIGHT JOIN`s, you can swap the join order of the second query above.)

If you wish to only produce results when changes are actually present, you can define and populate a #temp table with the select results, and then only select from that temp table if non-empty.

```
CREATE TABLE #Differences (
    rc_subscription_id INT,
    src_contract_id INT,
    trgt_SubscriptionUUID INT,
    trgt_ContractUUID
)

INSERT #Differences
SELECT ...

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Differences)
    SELECT * FROM #Differences

DROP TABLE #Differences
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I guess you're right I am overcomplicating things. Thank you so much, I'll try what you have mentioned above!

Comment: It works great thank you so much!

Comment: A `NOT EXISTS` would be more idiomatic than a `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` and certainly a `RIGHT JOIN` is unusual